# Problem with serving Angular and .Net core application on localhost on virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to run an application from a virtual machine on Azure but I'm stuck with some kind of a problem which I can't figure out. Application front end is Angular and backend is .net core 3.1. Also I'm using ngrok to tunnel my virtual machine localhost port.
When I run it localy on my computer everything works fine but when I run it on the virtual machine and try to access it from the internet there is an error and it's not working.(GET http://localhost:5000/api/Blog/famous net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
[Access from my computer img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV5jh.png)
This is a screenshot from accessing app localy on the virtual machine while working fine:
[access from VM img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu9K9.jpg)

Is that CORS related problem or if it's not what else can it be?
Here is my StartUp.cs:
[code](https://justpaste.it/8j0vo)

Comment: Please check if the ports on which angular and .net application are running are added in the inbound port rules under networking in the VM. If not added , please add them
If it is added, please  check if  these ports are added in the firewall inside the VM. If not added, please add them

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @RamaraoAdapa-MT, The problem seems to be with NSG rules blocking outside connectivity to the application, as you can access the application inside the virtual machine.
Please follow the below steps add the rule

You can add this rule yourself by going to the Azure Portal,

1.Select the Virtual Machines blade (left hand side Portal screen)

2.Select your Virtual Machine and on the screen that open select Networking

3.Within Networking click on the Add Inbound Port Rule  button

4.When the new tab opens you will need to enter the follow details,

5.Source - any

6.Source port range leave as a *

7.Destination - any

8.Destination port ranges – 5000(Port Number which your application is listening)

9.Priority - can be left as is, but the lower the number the higher the priority given

10.Name - Can be what you like

11.Select Add.

And then login to Virtual machine.

1. Click Windows Firewall>>Advanced settings
2. Click Inbound Rules in the left side of the window.
3. Click New Rule in the right side of the window.
   4.Click Port>>Click Next>> Click either TCP or UDP>>Click Specific local ports.
4. Type a port number>>Click Next
5. Click allow the connection>>Click next
6. Click any network types You’d like to allow>>Click Next>>Give the Name and Click Finish

After adding try to restart the machine once and try accessing from your local machine.

Comment: Followed every step from what you suggested and it is still the same. One thing I've noticed is that there is a security rule in Azure portal which denies all inbound connections (Priority-65500 DenyAllInbound Port-Any,Protocol-Any,Source-Any,Destination-Any,Action-Deny) but there is no option to delete it and it comes preconfigured.

Comment: How are you trying to access the app from outside network? Try to use public IP of the VM  and see if that works. (Example. 10.10.10.10:5000).

Comment: I'm accessing VM with the public IP 40.117.253.18. When I try to access 40.117.253.18:5000 browser says the same error (err connection refused). App is hosted on IIS.